# how to use two form's post value together

Tags: php, sql

I have a form on a page like:

```
     <form action='search.php' method='POST'>
     <input type='text' name='specialist' />
     <input type='submit' name='submit' />
     </form>
```

on search page there is another form like

```
     <form action='' method='POST'>
     <input type='submit' name='anygender' />
     </form>
```

then i am using

```
if(isset($_POST['anygender'])){
$speciality = $_POST['speciality'];
echo $speciality;
$a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM find_doctor WHERE  doctor_type LIKE '%$speciality%'");
while ($b = mysql_fetch_array($a)){
echo "<img src='$b[image]' height='150px' width='300px'>"."</br>";
echo $b['name']."</br>";
echo $b['doctor_type']."</br>";  
echo $b['location']."</br>";
echo $b['insurance']."</br>";
echo $b['comments']."</br>";
echo $b['address']."</br>";

}
}
```

then $specialist is showing blank and sql query not working..I want to use both form's post value together.Please tell me how to use first form post value in this. Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot submit two forms at the same time like this, that's not how it works. You'll either need to use jquery / js to copy the data from one form over into the other, or simply one have one form.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need two forms?

```
 <form action='index.php' method='POST'>
    <input type='text' name='specialist' />
    <input type='submit' name='anygender' />
    <input type='submit' name='submit' />
    </form>
```

Maybe you can use one form and check buttom?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. Check  $_POST['submit'] in if condition.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $speciality = $_POST['speciality'];
    echo $speciality;
    $a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM find_doctor WHERE  doctor_type LIKE '%$speciality%'");
    while ($b = mysql_fetch_array($a)){
    echo "<img src='$b[image]' height='150px' width='300px'>"."</br>";
    echo $b['name']."</br>";
    echo $b['doctor_type']."</br>";  
    echo $b['location']."</br>";
    echo $b['insurance']."</br>";
    echo $b['comments']."</br>";
    echo $b['address']."</br>";

    }
    }
```